# If $p$ is prime and $a^p\equiv b^p\pmod p$, then $a^p\equiv b^p\pmod {p^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've tried using congruence properties, the Euler theorem and the Fermat little theorem since the problem is in that section of the textbook but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $a^p\equiv b^p$ (mod $p$) then Fermat's little theorem implies that $a\equiv b$ (mod $p$). Therefore $b=a+kp$ for some integer $k$, and using the binomial theorem we get
$$ b^p=(a+kp)^p=a^p+{p\choose 1}a^{p-1}kp+cp^2$$
where $c$ is some integer. Since ${p\choose 1}=p$, it follows that $b^p\equiv a^p$ (mod $p^2$).

Comment: Or notice that $$a^p-b^p=(a-b)\left(a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+\cdots+b^{p-1}\right)$$

and $$a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+\cdots+b^{p-1}\equiv b^{p-1}\cdot p\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$